# Unable to run Android Studio emulator from an existing project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm new in app development and I just started my internship not too long ago , and
I'm currently working on an existing project , and I've been trying to build and run it on android studio, however it kept on giving me error messages.
Its been several days, and I dont know what else to do,

Here are the error messages, when I type

a-run on Android

```
info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
##############################

Using react.gradle in your project is deprecated! You should move to "apply plugin: com.facebook.react"
react.gradle is going to be removed in a future React Native project and your project will not build anymore.
You can use the template as a reference:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/template/android/app/build.gradle

##############################
WARNING:DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
Using it has no effect, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :libs:SalesforceReact.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :libs:SalesforceReact was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'general', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.0' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :libs:SalesforceReact.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :libs:SalesforceReact was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'general', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.0' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

    at makeError (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\...\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Here are the code on build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHLqA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYsLg.png)

I've updated the version of all the dependencies,
as well changing

**configurations.compile => configurations.implementation**
Also
**I existed the IDE window.Open the project from androidStudio and selected setting.gradle**

it still gave me the same error messages when I do npm start

I'm not sure whats going on, it'll be much appreciated if someone can help!
Thank you!

Comment: Please do not use code images copy/past it inside the question with a good formatting

Comment: It seems you are using Salesforce-related SDK or packages. Review `package.json` and check any dependencies related to Salesforce and review their documentation.

Comment: It should be this package - https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out or remove this line form `android/App/build.gradle`

```
// apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```